# Why no not defined NameError raised in this example?

Tags: python

Why there's no NameError raised for variable `s` in below example?

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = defaultdict(lambda : len(s))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same reason that this works:

```
def foo():
    print(bar)

bar = 'baz'

foo()
```

The `lambda` only *defines* a function. By the time that function is called and it *attempts* to access `s`, `s` exists.